# Can we unify every pair of inner models of ZFC by a same hierarchy?

Tags: logic, set-theory

**Definition:** Fix a ground model $V$ of ZFC. Let $F:V\rightarrow V$ be a definable class function (we call it an operator). The hierarchy $W^F$ corresponding to $F$ is defined as follows:

$$W^F_0:=\emptyset$$
$$\text{Forall}~~~\alpha\in \mathrm{Ord}~~~~~W^F_{\alpha+1}:=F(W^F_{\alpha})$$
$$\text{Forall}~~~\alpha\in \mathrm{Limit}~~~~~W^F_{\alpha}:=\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha} W^F_\beta$$
$$W^F:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}} W^F_\alpha$$

**Example:** If we define $P:V\rightarrow V$ to be $\forall x\in V~~~~~P(x):=\{y\in V\mid y\subseteq x\}$ then for every model $M$ of ZFC we have $M\models V=W^P$.

> **Question 1:** Let $M\subseteq N$ be two models of ZFC. Are there two operators $F:M\rightarrow M$ definable in $M$ and $F':N\rightarrow N$ definable in $N$ such that $M\models V=W^F$ and $N\models V=W^{F'}$ and $F'$ extends $F$ (i.e. $\forall x\in M~~~~~F'(x)=F(x)$)?
>
> **Question 2:** If the answer of above question is negative, is the following weaker version true?
>
> For each pair $M\subseteq N$ of models of ZFC there is a model $K$ of ZFC and three operators $F:M\rightarrow M$ definable in $M$, $F':N\rightarrow N$ definable in $N$ and $F'':N\rightarrow N$ definable in K such that $M\subseteq N\subseteq K$, $M\models V=W^F$, $N\models V=W^{F'}$, $K\models V=W^{F''}$ and $F''$ extends both $F, F'$ (i.e. $\forall x\in M~~~~~F''(x)=F(x)$ and $\forall x\in N~~~~~F''(x)=F'(x)$)?

Comment: "Can we unify any pair of inner models?" is ambiguous: It could mean "Is there any pair of inner models that we can unify?" or it could mean "Is it the case that for any pair of models, no matter which pair, we can unify them?".  If the latter was intended, just changing "any" to "every" would disambiguate it without complicating the sentence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I edited the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume all models are transitive.*

For question (1), the answer is: we can unify $M\subseteq N$ only if $M=N$ or $On^M\subsetneq On^N$. The proof is by induction: if $F'\upharpoonright M=F$, then for each $\alpha\in On^M$ we must have $W^F_\alpha\in M$.

Moreover, if $M$ is definable in $N$ and $On^M\subsetneq On^N$, then $M\subseteq N$ is unifiable: let $F$ be powerset with respect to $M$, and let $F'(X)=(\mathcal{P}(X))^M$ for $X\in M$, and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ otherwise.

For question (2), do you want $F'': N\rightarrow N$ (as written) or $F'': K\rightarrow K$ (which seems better)?